# Dynamically added path in URL going next to the variables. How can I move it before variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Just some intro:

In ecommerce template, "Symfony" based I'm loading all the products from available pages (Infinite scroll) using AJAX request. Everything working perfect when I have clear URL like this:

```
http://example.com/path
```

I'm loading products from available pages with ajax request, here some code to check (Note, not the whole functional code, but the part which affects URL):

```
$().ready(function(){
   infiniteCollectionInit('{{ (request.url~'page1.ajax') }}');    
});

function infiniteCollectionLoad(url, mode){
   infiniteCollectionPage++;
   url = url.replace('page1.ajax', 'page' + infiniteCollectionPage + '.ajax');
}
```

This simply adding `page1.ajax, page2.ajax ...` at the end of the URL

The problem starting at the point when filters are used in page, In that case the URL transforms to this:

```
http://example.com/path/?mode=grid&max=60&min=0&sort=newest
```

Now when scrolling down and it need to load next page's items the URL is:

```
http://example.com/path/?mode=grid&max=60&min=0&sort=newestpage1.ajax
```

Can anyone help me out to add the `page1.ajax` before variables like this:

```
http://example.com/path/page1.ajax?mode=grid&max=60&min=0&sort=newest
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
var u = new URL("http://example.com/path/?mode=grid&max=60&min=0&sort=newest")
var newUrl = u.origin + u.pathname + 'page.ajax' + u.search;
```

If URL is reused from the previous one than you might need to replace u.pathname with a fixed path. Otherwise you keep on adding to it.

Comment: this works just perfect. Exactly what I wanted. 

Thanks a lot.